# Form to Modify SharePoint List without adding rows

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, power-automate, powerapp

I currently have a SharePoint list that is feeds into a Power BI for data reporting. Editing this list is clunky and was wondering if there is way to modify the list rows by a form entry. The way this list is set up is a column for the employee's name and a bunch of Date columns of when they were certified for certain required certifications for their job.

Is there a way to create a form that will collect the employees name, which column to edit, and the new date to update the column? And what is the best way to do? Any example Power Automate scripts or anything to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Below is an example similar to how my list is set up:

[image]

I want the form to know which certification type and to update the date for that employee without creating a new row.

Comment: Any issues with using SharePoint default list forms? Also, you can customize list forms using Power Apps, check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form

Comment: Hi, does my answer help you in any way? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint online modern experience, you can either use the SharePoint default list forms OR you can customize the list forms using one of the methods given below:

**Power Apps**:

Check below documentations for customizing SharePoint online modern experience list forms using Power Apps (low code platform, easy to customize, coding experience not required heavily):

1. [Customize SharePoint list form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-apps/get-started/create-your-first-custom-form)
2. [Customize a Microsoft Lists or SharePoint form by using Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form)

---

**SharePoint Framework**:

In SharePoint online, you can also customize list forms using SPFx form customizer extension.

While using SPFx form customizer extension, you have to build everything custom on your own including UI of list forms, auto-populating field values for edit forms and saving the form field values back to SharePoint list.

**Documentation**: [Build your first Form Customizer extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-form-customizer)

Check this SPFx sample which will help you to get started with: [SPFx form customizer to override the default list behavior](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/main/samples/react-formcustomizer-customers)

Also, check these videos:

1. [How to create custom list forms with SharePoint Framework](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPvNR2nP2Xk)
2. [Building polished form experiences with SPFx form customizer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OkOl6anqvc4)